# Homotopy type of the simplicial action groupoid

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory

Let $X$ be a simplicial $G$-set, where $G$ is a simplicial group. What is the homotopy type of the simplicial action groupoid $X//G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the nerve of $X//G \in Gpd(sSet)$ to get a bisimplicial set (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bisimplicial+set), then take the diagonal, or the Artin-Mazur codiagonal (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/codiagonal). Either of the resulting simplicial sets represent the homotopy type. Pick the one which is better for what you need it for.

Comment: From this you also see that it is just the Borel construction (associated if you prefer to geometric realisations).

Comment: Torsten, the Borel construction know is for a discrete group $G$. Does the Borel construction also have a analogue for a simplicial group $G$?

Comment: It works for a topological group too! You just need a contractible free $G$-simplicial set, and this is supplied by $WG$. I'm not sure of the exact relation that Torsten mentions, off the top of my head...

Comment: David, your geometric realization ought to work for an simplicial object in ${\bf{Cat}}$ too, right?

Comment: Yep! It does  .